# Why look at him? Vs 'Why to look at him?

Tags: prepositions

Check out these sentences:

> He does indecent gestures at me ~ But **why look** at him? Simply ignore him. 
>   I cannot concentrate on my studies ~ **Why think** of her? 
>   He scolded me unnecessarily ~ But **why talk** in between? Keep mum.

In those all answers, no infinitive markers are used i.e. "***Why to*** look"; "***Why to*** think", and so on.

Is it okay to omit *IMs* while talking that way? Furthermore, if it's okay talking, is it okay *writing* as well?

Comment: In case you might forget (I think we've discussed this once), the word *to* in a *to*-infinitive is not a preposition.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, I goofed up! though I don't remember our conversation, if any :(

Comment: I don't think *to* is "omitted" because adding it in would be strange.  But as rewobs explains, you're right that these are bare infinitival interrogatives.

Comment: *\*Simply ignore*, though, is ungrammatical ― *ignore* needs a direct object: *Simply ignore him.*

Comment: @snailplane I see. I thought it works intransitively as well. OALD has no such classification mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's right in both senses. The bare infinitive is used in many cases including this form. ("Why+ bare infinitive...?")

They can be used as a part of suggestions rather than real questions and an answer isn't necessarily expected.

A clear example:

> "Why sell these tools? They might be useful in the future"

That way it would sound **less direct** than other forms like:

> "Why are **you** selling these tools?"

Comment: +1 for *They can be used as a part of suggestions..* that's what I thought as well. My examples are evidences of that.